# AutoCorrelation Matlab - Wolfram Alpha

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am trying to get the auto-correlation of

> {1, 0, 0, 1}

using matlab as follow:

```
X = [1, 0, 0, 1];
R = xcorr(X); % not normalized
R(length(X):length(R))
```

This gives me the following output

> 2 0 0 1

While calculating it by hand and also using Wolframe Alpha, I get the following result

> {2, 1, 0, 1}

Here is the link to how I calculated it using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ListCorrelate%5B%7B1,%200,%200,%201%7D,%20%7B1,%200,%200,%201%7D,%20%7B1%7D%5D)

I have also tried using `autocorr` function of matlab, I got the following which still is not correct:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

The Matlab computes non-periodic signals, while on Wolfram, it computes periodic correlation

That's the reason :D